# Is it possible to prevent a Child/Parent relationship on a bug?

Tags: tfs

We're using TFS 2017 on-premise, with an Agile template on our project.

If a user creates a bug and adds a link type of parent or child where the other work item is also a bug, it breaks the backlog board. You get a message telling you that the board ordering is broken,  with a hyperlink on how to fix it.

Is there a way to remove Child and Parent from the Link Type drop-down list, where the source work item type is Bug?

Answer (score 1):

No, we can not prevent or disable that. You may write a custom task with rest api to fix relations:

1. Find work items with relations: [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
2. Update work item: 1. [Remove a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#remove_a_link) 2. [Add a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#add_a_link)